# QField - application size and hidden data

Tags: qfield, memory, photos, storage

I am collecting some data using QField in Ethiopia. Usually, I am collecting points (.shp) with photos (text field with link to the photo/attachment).

I accidentally deleted the DCIM folder. However, I recognized that the size of QField grows each day rapidly. Today, QField in my tablet has a size of 4.63 GB. So it seems that data which I collected are backed up somewhere in the application.

Is this correct? Can I get somehow my deleted data? Or can I reinstall QField without debts? I need more space at memory and 4.63 GB is too big for one application.